# Control the delay in execution of a repeat task for Mono

Tags: spring-boot, project-reactor, reactor

I am trying to implement a polling mechanism . I would like to increase or decrease the polling interval based on some conditions.I am using Mono.repeat with delayElements for performing the repeat task with an interval.But I am not able to figure out a way to modify the delay based on some criteria.

````
Mono.just(1).
    repeat().
    delayElements(getPollingInterval()).
    takeUntil((s)->
      {

          if(checkForEndCriteria()){
              log.info("Critera to end reached);
              return true;
          }
          return false;
      }).
    log().
    subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()).
    flatMapSequential(x -> {
        List<Event> eventList = getEvents(id, lastItemTimeStamp);;
        if (!eventList.isEmpty()) {
            //Recieving events now. So want to decrease the interval.
            return Flux.fromIterable(eventList);
        } else {
        //There are no events happening .So I would like
        //to increase the delay of repeat task by 1 sec

            return Flux.just(buildHeartBeatEvent());
        }
    }).
    onErrorResume(error -> {
        log.error("Error occurred", error);
        return Flux.error(error);
    });```
````

Comment: Why do you want to use reactor to poll?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this with the `Flux.<Duration>generate()`:

```
        Flux
            .<Duration>generate(sink -> {
                Date date = [NEXT_DATE];
                if (date != null) {
                    long millis = date.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();
                    sink.next(Duration.ofMillis(millis));
                }
                else {
                    sink.complete();
                }
            })
            .concatMap(duration ->
                    Mono.delay(duration)
                    ...
            )
            .repeat();
```

So, every time we come back to the `generate()` with that `repeat()` we can take a look into some state to obtain the next execution `Date`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this. But the problem I face is that in this approach first the generate is creating a flux until the condition is satisfied  . In my usecase the end condition isn't fixed. It is based on the user activity. I am continuously polling the data base .  I am trying to increase the delay in polling based on availability on new events. If there are no events happening then increase the delay. If a new event happened then reset the polling interval to the initial value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using delayElements for a fixed delay, I suggest you to use [Mono.delay](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#delay-java.time.Duration-) inside your flatMapSequential just after your Flux using [concatWith](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concatWith-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-), in that way you can control easily its duration according to your elements.

You can also use [repeat(BooleanSupplier)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#repeat-java.util.function.BooleanSupplier-) instead of repeat + takeUntil and [defaultIfEmpty](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#defaultIfEmpty-T-) to clean up a little bit the code.

I hope something like this can help you:

```
Mono.fromCallable(() -> getEvents(id, lastItemTimeStamp)).
subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()).
flatMapMany(eventList -> Flux.fromIterable(eventList).
                              defaultIfEmpty(buildHeartBeatEvent()).
                              concatWith(Mono.delay(eventList.isEmpty() ?
                                          getEmptyListPollingInterval() : 
                                          getPollingInterval()).
                                         then().cast(Event.class))).
log().
repeat(this::checkForEndCriteria);
```